# Trigonometry identity proof......$x\sin\theta + y\cos\theta$

Tags: trigonometry

How to prove this identity?

$x\sin\theta + y\cos\theta = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}(\sin(\theta + \tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x}))$

Comment: Caution for using $\tan^{-1} (\cdot)$, better version for the identity is $x\sin \theta+y\cos \theta = \operatorname{sgn} (x) \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \sin \left( \theta+\tan^{-1} \frac{y}{x}  \right)$

Answer (score 4):

- Divide each side by $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$
- Set $\tan\alpha=\frac{y}{x}$, so that $\alpha=\tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x})$, $\sin\alpha=\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$, and $\cos\alpha=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$.
- The quantity on left hand side is then $\sin\theta\cos\alpha+\cos\theta\sin\alpha=\sin(\theta+\alpha)$, as required.

Comment: +1 for including enough, yet answering in a format that matched the question (that is, tersely).

Answer (score 0):

let $\frac{y}{x}=tan\,\alpha$ , we have
$$\alpha=tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$$ and
$$cos\alpha=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$

$$x\,sin\,\theta+y\,cos\,\theta=x(sin\,\theta+\frac{y}{x}\,cos\,\theta)=x\frac{sin\,\theta\,cos\,\alpha+cos\,\theta\,sin\,\alpha}{cos\,\alpha}=x\frac{sin(x+\alpha)}{cos\,\alpha}$$
as a result 
$$x\,sin\,\theta+y\,cos\,\theta=x\frac{sin(x+tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right))}{\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}sin\left(x+tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

$x\sin\theta + y\cos\theta = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$
\begin{align}
\sin(\theta + \tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x}))=\sin \theta \cos(\tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x}))+\sin (\tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x})) \cos \theta \tag{1}
\end{align}
Let $\theta=\tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x})$, then $\tan \theta=\frac{y}{x}$, so that by computing the quantities  $\sin (\tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x}))=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}$ and $\cos (\tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x}))=\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}$.

Substituting in (1), we get
\begin{align}
\sin(\theta + \tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x}))&=\sin \theta \cos(\tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x}))+\sin (\tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x})) \cos \theta \tag{1}
\\
&=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}\sin\theta + \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}\cos\theta
\end{align}